# How do RabbitMQ per connection flow-control block client from publishing messages?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, middleware

I'm new to RabbitMQ and I really want to figure out the detailed implementation of per connection flow control of RabbitMQ.
I read the source code of RabbitMQ server but can't find how flow-control blocking rabbitmq-java-client from publishing messages.

In `rabbit_reader.erl` I find control_throttle method which most likely do the flow control work.

```erlang
% rabbitmq-server v3.7.x rabbit_reader.erl
control_throttle(State = #v1{connection_state = CS,
                             throttle = #throttle{blocked_by = Reasons} = Throttle}) ->
    Throttle1 = case credit_flow:blocked() of
                  true  ->
                    Throttle#throttle{blocked_by = sets:add_element(flow, Reasons)};
                  false ->
                    Throttle#throttle{blocked_by = sets:del_element(flow, Reasons)}
             end,
    State1 = State#v1{throttle = Throttle1},
    case CS of
        running -> maybe_block(State1);
        %% unblock or re-enable blocking
        blocked -> maybe_block(maybe_unblock(State1));
        _       -> State1
    end.
```

But in `maybe_block` method, it will send a "connection.blocked" message to client, which I find in rabbit-java-client is high-water-mark blocking message, not flow-control blocking.

So how does flow control block the client from publishing messages?

Where are the codes for blocking?

Does it block only on server-side or both on server and client side?

Thanks